# ASP.NET MVC POST won't send back second ocurrence of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

The class Unidade:

```
public class Unidade
{
    public int UnidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Is used twice in the class Insumo, as Unidade and UnidadeConsumo

```
public class Insumo
{
    public int InsumoId { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int UnidadeId { get; set; }
    public Unidade Unidade { get; set; }
    public int UnidadeConsumoId { get; set; }
    public Unidade UnidadeConsumo { get; set; }
}
```

To edit Insumo there are two actions EDIT in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    Insumo insumo = db.Insumos.Find(id);
    if (insumo == null) return HttpNotFound();
    ViewBag.UnddId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeId);
    ViewBag.UndConsId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeConsumoId);
    return View(insumo);
}
```

And the POST EDIT:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "InsumoId,Apelido,Descricao,UnidadeId,UnidadeConsumoId")] Insumo insumo)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(insumo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    ViewBag.UnddId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeId);
    ViewBag.UndConsId = new SelectList(db.Unidades, "UnidadeId", "Apelido", insumo.UnidadeConsumoId);
    return View(insumo);
    }
```

The view to display the fields to edition, comprised of two dropdown lists to select both units is:

```
@model Gestor.Models.Insumo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Alterar";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Alterar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Insumo</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.Partial("CopyEdit")

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Gravar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Retornar a lista", "Index")
</div>
```

And the partial view CopyEdit in the center:

```
@model Gestor.Models.Insumo
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InsumoId)

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apelido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apelido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apelido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnidadeId, "Unidade", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("UnddId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnidadeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnidadeConsumoId, "Unidade de Consumo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("UndConsId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UnidadeConsumoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is thta whrn returned to the POST Edit action, all fields are ok, but UnidadeConsumoId is always 0, what doesn't even exists in the database?

Can someone tell me why is it not returning the expected value, i.e. the selected value in the dropdown list reflecting the id of if?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your current code is rendering a SELECT element with `name` attribute value `UndConsId`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="UndConsId">
   <!-- options -->
</select>
```

For model binding to work, the input element `name`  attribute value should match with the parameter/property name used in the http post action method. Your parameter name is `UnidadeConsumoId`, not `UndConsId`

To fix this issue,  pass `UnidadeConsumoId` as the first parameter of the `DropDownList` method call so that it will render the SELECT element with `name`  `UnidadeConsumoId`. You can pass the `ViewBag.UndConsId` as the second parameter to explicitly specify the collection to be used to build the SELECT element.

This should work

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnidadeConsumoId", ViewBag.UndConsId as SelectList, 
                                      new { @class = "form-control" })
```